# Migrate from AWS ElasticBeanstalk to Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We have this Java 11 application deployed in AWS ElasticBeanstalk, and we're exploring other deployment alternatives with Google Cloud.

We use c5.2xlarge instances and need to have at least 16 instances running at all times. We also use *Immutable* deployments that allow us to control traffic and potential errors on releases.

Checking Google Cloud's `App Engine`, the *standard* doesn't seem to have the capacity necessary and the *flexible* doesn't seem to support Java 11. `Cloud run` or `GKE` seem like good alternatives, but more expensive, apparently. Compute Engine seems the best, but we could lose the releasing strategy we currently have.

Using Google Cloud, is there any other option or path we would evaluate?

Comment: have you tried checking [Anthos](https://cloud.google.com/anthos), you can check also this [Anthos technical overview](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/docs/concepts/overview) if this will suffice for your deployments.

Answer (score 0):

you can explore [Anthos](https://cloud.google.com/anthos) for more detailed information see this documentation on [Anthos technical overview](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/docs/concepts/overview) if this will suffice for your deployments.